# Adding more transitions to SharePoint picture library slideshow web part

Tags: picture-library, slider

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 site. Currently, we are trying to add new transitions to one of the picture library slideshow web parts that exist on our site. 
    Right now, the slide show only uses a fade-in/fade-out animation to display new pictures. Is there any way I could make the web part use a .js plugin to perform transitions? Or is there any other way to achieve this through SharePoint's UI?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 solutions that will work for your situation:

**Solution 1:** http://www.markrackley.net/2013/07/29/a-simple-jquery-content-slider-for-sharepoint-200720102013-and-o365/

**Solution 2:** https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544663/Image-Carousel-Slider-in-SharePoint-2010